# Replace/remove 2 characters with space in a sed one-liner

Tags: regex, sed

Merciful overlords of sed, here's my raw output:

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sun Jan 10 02:16 - 06:52  (04:36)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Jan  6 02:00 - 06:52 (4+04:52)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sun Jan  3 00:39 - 06:52 (7+06:13)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sat Jan  2 02:40 - 06:52 (8+04:12)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sat Jan  2 02:39 - 06:52 (8+04:13)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 06:56 - 06:52 (10+23:56)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 02:43 - 03:17  (00:34)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 00:51 - 03:17  (02:26)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 07:14 - 03:17  (20:02)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 05:30 - 07:14  (01:44)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 05:18 - 07:14  (01:55)
```

My desire is to remove the parentheses in the last column with a sed one-liner, instead of using this unelegant and rookie-like snippet that is almost egregiously obvious to use:

```
[root@OEL7 ~]# last reboot | sed -e 's/(//g' | sed -e 's/)//g'
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sun Jan 10 02:16 - 07:12  04:55
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Jan  6 02:00 - 07:12 4+05:11
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sun Jan  3 00:39 - 07:12 7+06:32
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sat Jan  2 02:40 - 07:12 8+04:31
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sat Jan  2 02:39 - 07:12 8+04:32
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 06:56 - 07:12 **11+00:15**
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 02:43 - 03:17  00:34
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Dec 30 00:51 - 03:17  02:26
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 07:14 - 03:17  20:02
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 05:30 - 07:14  01:44
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Tue Dec 29 05:18 - 07:14  01:55
```

I believe I've performed my due diligence before posting (including sifting through some of the suggested posts before publicizing this one) but the examples I've found do not meet my criteria:

1. mandatory use of sed
2. achieve the result in the shortest possible manner, without piping, etc.

Should any of you however be privy of a solution on SO that I may have missed I'd be eternally grateful for any URLs, pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capture group to match all between the parenthesis followed by `$` to assert the end of the string. Testing this on a mac, apparently there can be spaces at the end.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
sed -E 's/\(([^()]+)\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2FkyS5/1) | [Sed demo](https://tio.run/##ndGxboMwEIDhvU9xiioFioDznQ3kxNguXVupAxCJpEhdmlQ1Gfr01Aa1oRtlsz18@n13aO3bMNjuFeIH2Nq0DoJqH4RNFNZhVYn9aI@dNM3dbVqrdAtlWcLmszuczz0A2C/bd@8w3ThRmGDMlCdUJJzA0@UEj@0JFAKSqAxiwEwMAQSohbPwZiH04uo8BJmHEH@hQEdOMrRY@kkCBkTh3VXKI3dQvFxq@0ki36RnTYVvUrRSmjdNEv9rTvfdERhH4TrwQGFE7F5WUe577CkWlfvducHpVRCKUXOIhJYXPV@6EaIdYC5KzyBCQVoFGeFxcyPoipRovRJSxV/ImHAzDN8)

Without using `-E`

```
sed 's/(\([^()]*\))[[:space:]]*$/\1/'
```

See another [sed demo](https://tio.run/##ndE9T8MwEIDhnV9xqpDqNGpyvnM@esrIxAoSQ5pKabHEQotwOvDrg50IGraQzfbw6PXdsXVvfe/sK6xdqvaqPqio2eyjqK7FfbQnK02zuU/3Ol1DVVWw@rTHy6UDAPflOvsO440TjQlumYqEyoQTeLqe4bE9g0ZAEp3DFjCXjAAUGuE8upsJvfi0AEEeIMRfSJnYSxnNln6SgAFReHeTitgfNM@X2m6UKDSZSVMZmjQtlKZNo8T/mtODPQHjINwGrjTGxP5lEeW/x4Fi0UXYnR@cWQShZHoKkdD8ouerHSDaARaizQQiFKRFUCY8bG4AfZEWYxZCuvwLZVm06vtv)

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly but it appears it doesn't work:

`[root@OEL7 ~]# last reboot | sed -E 's/\(([^()]+)\)$/\1/' 
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Sun Jan 10 02:16 - 07:41  (05:24)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.28.3. Wed Jan  6 02:00 - 07:41 (4+05:40)`

You have my wholehearted gratitude for the URLs though, I will put them both to good use. Many, many thanks again.

Comment: @MaximusSuperbus I have updated the answer to account for optional spaces at the end.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you only need:

```
last reboot | sed 's,[()],,g'
```

Comment: mirific, that worked like a charm and the brevity of it all is exemplary!

Would you be so kind however as to explain the commas to a mortal such as myself? I seem to be stuck in the old adage that sed delimits stuff through `/` rather than `,`.

Comment: Note that this does not only replace the () in the last column.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: sure, it replaces all `(` and `)`. It works with `last` only because parenthesis are only used in the last column. But, that's the simplest solution way to remove parenthesis that I think OP was looking for.